# как в JS сделать какую-то функцию принудительно синхронной?

Tags: javascript, jquery

есть некий простой код который должен дергать сервер и брать данные с php скрипта. Но Алерт вызывается черезчур рано -- до того как ответ с сервера прийдет. Как пофиксить?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(
        function(){
            var discount = 'noDiscount';
            GetTextFromPage('http://discount.com.net/get_discount.php', discount);

            alert(discount);
        }
    );

    function GetTextFromPage(page, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: page,
            async:true,
            dataType : 'jsonp',   //you may use jsonp for cross origin request
            crossDomain:true,
            success: function(data, status, xhr) {
                callback(data);
            }
        });
    };
</script>
```

пытаюсь понять как сделать GetTextFromPage синхронной в то время как внутры был асинхронный вызов.

Фактически, сделать то же что делает await в C#. Вроде:

```
function(){
    var discount = 'noDiscount';
    AWAIT GetTextFromPage('http://discount.com.net/get_discount.php', discount);
    alert(discount);
}
```

Comment: Советы в ответе-дубликате. Там расписаны варианты... Да и собственно если ты написал `callback(data);` - т.е. понимаешь что в callback надо/можно отдавать результат, то почему его ожидаешь в `alert`?)

Comment: ну ты по-сути уже его и написал `GetTextFromPage('http://discount.com.net/get_discount.php', myHandler);
 
function GetTextFromPage(str, callback) {
 /* какие-то действия*/
 callback("datasdfsdf");    
}

function myHandler(data) {
 console.log(data);    
}` ......... но почитай примеры в вопросе-дубликате

Comment: Используй генераторы из ES6.

Comment: *"Фактически, сделать то же что делает await в C#"* ну так и делайте await - он в ES2017 будет введен

Answer (score 0):

Потому что нужно вызывать `alert`, а вообще `alert` это плохой тон в использовании, лучше используйте `console.log()`, в самой функции `GetTextFromPage`

Вариант №1

```
    $(document).ready(
        function(){
            GetTextFromPage('http://discount.com.net/get_discount.php', 'noDiscount');
        }
    );

    function GetTextFromPage(page, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: page,
            async:true,
            dataType : 'jsonp',   //you may use jsonp for cross origin request
            crossDomain:true,
            success: function(data, status, xhr) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    };
</script>
```

Вариант №2

```
    $(document).ready(
        function(){
            GetTextFromPage('http://discount.com.net/get_discount.php',function(data){alert(data);});
        }
    );

    function GetTextFromPage(page, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: page,
            async:true,
            dataType : 'jsonp',   //you may use jsonp for cross origin request
            crossDomain:true,
            success: function(data, status, xhr) {
                callback(data);
            }
        });
    };
</script>
```

Comment: алерт исключительно для тестирования и не более того, на практике оно будет вставлять текст внутрь хтмл-а. 
Мне нужно будет использовать даный метод в нескольких местах и нужна универсальная функция для вытягивания данных вместо того что бы плодить дубликаты кода.

Comment: Да исключительно для тестирования и отладки правильно использовать `console.log()`, я подправил ответ и дописал вам вариант 2 он вам больше подойдет

Comment: а может все таки есть способ сделать метод принудительно синхронным?

Comment: В смысле принудительно?

Comment: ну вот скажем в шарпе все методы изначально синхронные. И что бы метод стал асинхронным нужно писать async перед обьявой метода. А если нужно подождать пока асинк метод закончит работу есть слово await при вызове метода. Вот мне нужна альтернатива await :) Эти все вложенные функции слишком громоздкие и плохочитабельные. Я и так плохо понимаю это все, а с таким подходом заплутатся раз плюнуть.